# In terraria mobile, how do you farm the slime staff?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I heard that the slime staff is the rarest item in terraria. And I wanted it so bad that I decided to farm it but I don't exactly know how to farm it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Terraria wiki's [Slime Staff](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Slime_Staff) page states:

> An easy way to get this staff is to use Slime Statues, with a thin
>   layer of lava.

The Slime Staff is only dropped by Slimes and Slimed Zombies, with a low 0.01% drop rate.
With this in mind, it may take time, but the Staff should eventually be found by using the aforementioned Statue method.

Comment: Ok I'll do that.

Comment: Or is you haven't found a Slime Statue, you can Try to farm the Slime Rain event when it starts, or just go outside during the event with a Water Candle on a Crafting Bench or Table with a Battle Potion.